# Using a Paremeter when opening a link in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I'm struggling a bit here so hopefully someone will be able to help me out.

We're trying to open up a file which is on our servers, by clicking on a link in an SSRS report (using the `Go To URL` part).

The link works fine when we put it in a web browser, so I know the problem isn't a security issue.

Basically it looks like this...

```
="\\servername\foldername\"+Parameters!ParameterName.Value+".pdf"
```

This only opens in the same window in a web browser - how do I get this to open in a new tab?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was needed to be done in this case to solve this, was it needed to be set out as follows:

="Javascript:void(window.open('file://[servername]/[foldername]/" + Parameters![ParameterName].Value + ".pdf','_blank'))"

Answer (score 0):

You can set that URL to be anything you want, including javascript.  This allows you to control how the link behaves, for example specifying the target for the link to open in:

```
="javascript:void(window.open('\\servername\foldername\"+Parameters!ParameterName.Value+".pdf','_blank'))"
```

In this case it is the `'_blank'` part of the javascript `window.open` function that targets either a new tab or a new window depending on your browser settings.

Comment: I don't know if it is just me, but this doesn't seem to work for me :(

Comment: *this doesn't seem to work for me* isn't very helpful in remotely diagnosing an issue here...  Perhaps you could add some screenshots to your question?  Ideally of both your report design and what happens when you click the URL in the browser.

Comment: Sorry - you're right - I should have been a bit clearer. So, when I put this in as an expression in report builder, it returns no errors, so I think "great, it's all going to work", when I click on it (when I actually run the report, after saving the change), nothing happens in the web browser - no error, but also no change in the page, nor is a new tab opened.

Comment: What does the URL point to when you right click the link and select `Copy Shortcut`?  Assuming you are using Internet Explorer?

Comment: In addition, as a test what happens when you use this as your URL expression: `="javascript:void(window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank'))"` ?

Comment: The google bit worked, When I copied the shortcut it said: void(window.open('%5C%5C[servername]%5C[foldername]%5C'+Parameters!]parametername].Value+'.pdf','_blank'))

Comment: Does that look correct to you?  You need to set the URL up as an expression starting with the `=` per my answer.  you should not see the `+Parameters!ParameterName.Value+` part - that should be the *value* held in that parameter.  Try manually creating the URL you require to your PDF, manually wrapping it in the Javascript and then pasting it into the URL bar and pressing enter.

Comment: For example, if your desired URL is `\\servername\foldername\ReportName.pdf`, try manually pasting `javascript:void(window.open('\\servername\foldername\ReportName.pdf','_blank'))` and see if that works.

Comment: If it does, then create your expression from that and work backwards.  You should end up with what I have in my answer.  Thinking about it, as you can see the `+Parameters!ParameterName.Value+` part, make sure you have your single and double quotes in the correct places.